# Angular2 setting view encapsulation globally

Tags: angular

I've decided to set `ViewEncapsulation` to `None` for all my components in my project.

So, how can I set `ViewEncapsulation.None` globally to whole project? instead of setting it in each of my components decorator.

*Note: Just for extra info, My deps are on RC.6*

**Edit**: The 2nd solution provided by Günter Zöchbauer also works on 2.1.2

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can set default view encapsulation by passing a custom `CompilerConfig`.
This feature was added in [RC.2](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc2-2016-06-15) (last item in the features list)

**1. You can set it on NgModule level**

**this way doesn't work anymore**

```
    @NgModule({
        // imports, declaration, bootstrap, etc..
        providers: [{
            provide: CompilerConfig, 
            useValue: new CompilerConfig({
                defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
            })
        }]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XB5vsY9t5cArDSlzGj4w?p=preview)

**2. Set it on bootstrap level (Thanks to yurzui)**

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
    {
        defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    }
]);
```

Please note that you ofc need to import `ViewEncapsulation` from `@angular/core`

**3. In more recent Angular versions this can be set in compiler options**

Caution: I haven't tried this myself yet.
This is just how I interpreted the docs:

In `tsconfig.json`

```
{ 
  ...,
  angularCompilerOptions: {
   defaultEncapsulation: 3;
  }
}
```

- https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options
- https://angular.io/api/core/CompilerOptions
- https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Thanks for your information. I've tried your answer and still unable to get it working. Please check my updated question. Am I missing something?

Comment: `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None });`

Comment: @yurzui did you try it? I saw that `boostrapModule()` takes `CompilerOptions` but that seems to be something different than `CompilerConfig`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I confirm his approach also works here.. Actually, both of yours work great.. Thanks for the answer..

Comment: I forgot the `.None` in my code. Also just tried it https://plnkr.co/edit/DT3jJeXxDyhOm5r07y5b?p=preview and I can confirm it's working.

Comment: If I set it at bootstrap level will it be applied to third party modules I use?

Comment: I haven't tried. I'd expect that, if they set it explicitly, this setting will be used, but where they left the default (not specified it - currently probably almost always the case), the new default will be applied.

Comment: first solution does not work now, please confirm and update the answer

Comment: This will not work wit AOT compilation, only with JIT. Now I have to use `--aot=false` for my production build.

Comment: I don't think this is limited to AoT.

Comment: does this override settings that are on a component?

Comment: The answer is outdated. This setting was moved to NgModule as far as I remember and the component setting overrides the module setting. There is no way to override the component setting because the component code (HTML, CSS) probably breaks if you override it.

Comment: None of the solutions seem to work any longer any idea how to globally set this in Angular 10?

Comment: I updated my answer. Not sure it's any good. I just looked at the docs.

Comment: It seems that it still doesn't work for JIT compiled components. There's a merge request but the edit hasn't been released yet: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/35534

Comment: According to [THIS](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12251#issuecomment-872613835) the 3rd option doesn't seem to be supported now...