# InterpolateProvider in angularjs 2

Tags: angular, angularjs-interpolate

I'm trying to do something similar to this interpolateProvider in AngularJS 2 but can not find how to do this similarly for

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `CompilerConfig` to `bootstrapModule` where you can configure a regular expression that defines what characters are used for interpolation:

```ts
var INTERPOLATION_REGEXP = /\{\{([\s\S]*?)\}\}/g; // default

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
    {
        interpolationRegexp: INTERPOLATION_REGEXP
    }
]);
```

See also [Angular2 setting view encapsulation globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452729/angular2-setting-view-encapsulation-globally)