# String intrapolation in Angular 2.0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a string like `{name} is my name. Greeting {sender}`

is there some module in angualar 2.0, so that i can do something like `string.format()` as we do in C#?

I know this can be done using vanila js custom method, but i want to know is there any module inside angular 2 to handle this. They use interpolation in template binding so how to do that with a normal string

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but if you want to override the interpolation syntax this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819407/interpolateprovider-in-angularjs-2

Comment: There is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. Angular itself doesn't provide anything.

Comment: I want to interpolate the string {name} is my name. Greeting {sender} to something like "Dinkar is my mane. Greeting codef0rmer". using something like string.formate("{name} is my name. Greeting {sender}","Dinkar","codef0rmer")

Answer (score 5):

Check ES6 [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It enables multi-line strings and string interpolation.

Example:

```
var name = 'John',
    age = 19;

console.log(`${name} is my name. I'm ${age}.`); 

// => John is my name. I'm 19.
```

TypeScript from version 1.4 supports ES6 Template literals and can compile them down to ES3/ES5 expressions.

Comment: i was looking something provided by the framework. Ends up creating prototype function for String and using it. Wonder this basic thing is not provided by the framework :(

Comment: If you're using Angular with TypeScript, then it's already available for use, since TypeScript from version 1.4 supports ES6 Template literals.

Answer (score 2):

By using the back tick, grave, character you can achieve string interpolation similar to c#.

```
`${name} is my name. Greeting ${sender}`
```

This is a feature of TypeScript but does not do any formatting such as specifying decimal places. I would recommend keeping your string definitions on a single line because I have seen multiline definitions mess up styles in certain editors.

Here is a great [article](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html) about template strings. The rest of the guide is a great resource for TypeScript in general.

Comment: this is not a typescript feature. you this is ES6 feature.

Answer (score 0):

I came up creating and prototype method for string class 
Created ***Extention.ts*** file with code

```
interface String {
   format: (o:Object) => string;
}

String.prototype.format = function (o) : string {
   return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
     function (a, b) {
       var r = o[b];
       return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
     }
   );
 };
```

then where i wanted to use the formatting i imported the extension file and use format method like

```
import '../../shared/interpolation'

export class ... {

    someMethod():void {
       var str = "{name} is my name. Greeting {sender}";
       let aa  = str.format({a:'dinkar',b:'Darth Vader'});
       console.log(aa);
    }
}
```