# Angular: setting ViewEncapsulation.None globally

Tags: angular

In my project, Angular adds css classes to HTML elements and components at runtime :

```
<div class="ng-tns-c99-6">..</div>
```

I've tried :

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

but it still adds the CSS class at runtime.

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453607/1283501) and tried to set ViewEncapsulation.None globally, but this doesn't affect it either, the CSS classes are still being added.

Is there a way to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set `ViewEncapsulation` globally. [Issue 18346](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18346) on GitHub suggests to allow setting it at the module level. The status of the issue is `Open` at the present moment.

> ### Set ViewEncapsulation per module #18346
>
> **Current behavior**
>
> Currently, we set the view encapsulation at the component level.
>
> ```
> @Component({
>   selector: 'song-track',
>   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
> })
> Meaning that if I want to use native Shadow DOM throughout my app, 
> I have to add that bit of configuration to every single component.
> ```
>
> **Expected behavior**
>
> It would be great if I could set it at the module level.
>
> ```
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [...],
>   declarations: [...],
>   providers: [
>       ...
>       { provide: ViewEncapsulationMode, useValue: ViewEncapsulation.Native },
>       ...
>   ],
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

Comment: the CSS classes are still added even when setting "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" inside the component's @Component() directive. Any idea why?

Comment: That is strange. The `ng-...` class is not added when I set `ViewEncapsulation.None`, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jpodx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Also, with the default `ViewEncapsulation`, I see an `_ngcontent...` attribute, not a class. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2lc2k?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks for the samples. I saw that ViewEncapsulation.None worked. Those classes I want to get rid of and whose names start with 'ng-tns-...' are still a mystery though, maybe Angular CDK related.

Comment: The classes maybe related to Angular Material. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896805/angular-material-ng-tns-class-changes-margin-of-items-in-my-table-can-use-css-t).

Comment: Just found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17492) and in Angular source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ed73d4f3ac6b542bf5ea3eb73fbe91e2ceabcdb4/packages/animations/browser/src/render/transition_animation_engine.ts#L112). It's Angular animations related then.