# Setting default ViewEncapsulation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2viewencapsulation

Is there currently a way to set a default ViewEncapsulation for the complete angular application?
Googled a bit but found only outdated answers, which do not work anymore.

would be a pain in the ass setting ViewEncapsulation.None to 200+ components :D

thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452729/angular2-setting-view-encapsulation-globally

Comment: found this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452729/angular2-setting-view-encapsulation-globally

Comment: @Chellappanவ  found already these topics, since 2020 are none of those working anymore sadly.

Comment: @s.stkvc just seen the comment. It seems It's not possible to set globally.